# Для чего на сайте с сериалами сам видеофайл размещают на другом сайт?

Tags: javascript, html

Учусь, делая сайт с сериалами для понимания как всё устроено. Смотрю код страницы популярного сайта с сериалом. В теге `<video>` указано ссылка на другой сайт с самим видеофайлом вот она:

```
src="https://r270104.kujo-jotaro.com/naruto/2/4.480.b7c24240b2287e9e.mp4?hash1=4ed09570c5d4339cd92331802eb74f25&hash2=e081e3a6c549939e4ae982e9b338faea"
```

если перейти и посмотреть код можно увидеть:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  </head>
  <body>
    <video controls="" autoplay="" name="media">
      <source src="https://r270104.kujo-jotaro.com/naruto/2/4.480.b7c24240b2287e9e.mp4?hash1=4ed09570c5d4339cd92331802eb74f25&amp;hash2=e081e3a6c549939e4ae982e9b338faea" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
  </body>
</html>
```

Может это делается, чтобы не заблокировали сайт из за пиратства? сейчас создаю свой плеер в конструкторе playerjs и там нужно указывать ссылку с которого загружается видео. Думаю, как это организовать, в файлах сайта своего создать папку с видеофайлами или же загрузить на видеохостинги.

Просмотрев другие подобные сайты увидел, что там также, только меняется адрес сайта, например: `aniboom.one`. Можно ли как то добавить к себе на сайт плеер `aniboom`?

Comment: Просто для распределения нагрузки по нескольким серверам

Comment: А причем здесь язык си?...